# GraphViz how to layout shapes evenly on a page

Tags: graphviz

I have a graph with a lot of objects. A number of these objects have no links. GraphVis lays these out on one long horizontal line on the top of the diagram.

Is there anyway to make GraphViz have a maximum width, so unconnected objects go on the next "line" ?

Answer (score 0):

Add invisible edges between them. This will force graphviz to layout these nodes like the ordinary ones.